# Classic ASP retrieving large amounts of data

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have a table that has over 148,000 rows, I have managed to display this by doing:

```
<%response.Buffer=false%>
```

However, this is far from ideal as it needs to be done on the server and it takes so long. Is there a better way of doing this?

Many Thanks, 
Joel

Comment: What about paging? 148,000 rows in a single page would be a lot of rows.

Comment: Why do you need to display 148,000 rows of data in one page? This is horrible usability.

Comment: Hey, I agree - but I was looking to use the data tables jQuery plugin. There are examples of server-side processing - but non of them are in ASP. I think I will convert one over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I agree with the others that displaying 148.000 rows on one page is madness, I just wanted to point your attention to how you should output the data.

Since you didn't specify any code, I'm assuming you're simply looping through your recordset to display the records, like so:

```
Do While Not RS.EOF
//Output
RS.MoveNext
Loop
```

This is a really inefficient way of working with data in classic ASP, since each time you're reading a field (i.e. RS("Name")) you're making a request to the database, and the same goes for each MoveNext and each EOF test. Instead you should use GetRows, to get all your elements from the recordset into an array, and then you can go ahead and close the connection to your database.

There's a good article on how to work with GetRows [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210619174118/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/aspfaqs/ShowFAQ.asp?FAQID=190)

Except from the article:

```
MyArray = rsMyRecordSet.GetRows()

//Close DB connection

Ubound(MyArray,1) 'Returns the Number of Columns
Ubound(MyArray,2) 'Returns the Number of Rows
For lnLoopCounter = 0 To Ubound(MyArray,2)
    Response.Write MyArray(0, lnLoopCounter) _
      & ", " _
      & MyArray(1, lnLoopCounter) _
      & "<BR>" & vbNewLine
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post but I just thought I'd let anyone who comes across this that I wrote a server side script just for this purpose.  Check it out at:

http://www.webmastersean.com/2012/11/datatables-classic-asp-server-side.html